# Cypress | using variables declared in beforeEach hook

Tags: mocha.js, cypress

In my e2e tests I'm declaring some variables in beforeEach hook to use them later in tests.

Current solution:

```
    beforeEach(() => {
      // some variables are declared here
      // using cy.wrap only for presentation purpose
      cy.wrap({ foo: 1 })
        .as('foo')
      cy.wrap({ bar: 2 })
        .as('bar')
    })

    it('some test', () => {
      cy.get('@foo')
        .then((foo) => {
          cy.get('@bar')
            .then((bar) => {
              // here I have access to these variables
            })
        })
    })
```

That works fine but what if I had 10 variables to pass to tests? Then I'd have 10 nested `.then` what doesn't look good.

I know that I could declare these variables in `context` using `let` and then have access to them in tests but it's not recommended way of handling variables in Cypress.

```
    let globalFoo
    let globalBar
    
    beforeEach(() => {
      // some variables are declared here
      // using cy.wrap only for presentation purpose
      cy.wrap({ foo: 1 })
        .then((foo) => {
          globalFoo = foo
        })
      cy.wrap({ bar: 2 })
        .then((bar) => {
          globalBar = bar
        })
    })

    it('some test', () => {
      // now I have access to them too
      cy.wrap(globalBar)
      cy.wrap(globalFoo)
    })
```

**Is there any way to pass many variables from beforeEach hook to tests and stay with clean code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this.*` notation to access cypress variables without a then callback:

```js
    beforeEach(() => {
      // some variables are declared here
      // using cy.wrap only for presentation purpose
      cy.wrap({ foo: 1 })
        .as('foo')
      cy.wrap({ bar: 2 })
        .as('bar')
    })

    it('some test', function() {
        // here I have access to these variables
        console.log(this.foo + this.bar)   
    })
```

Notice a function callback is used within the `it` statement as this won't work inside an arrow callback (`() => {}`)